# How to I can know performance indicators on the AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to I can know, for example, RAM size on the AWS instance?

I select `View details` on the needed instance, but I can't find any needed information about the productivity (CPU speed, Storage size, RAM):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CPU usage for your instance is reported in CloudWatch by default. The RAM and disk volume usage is only known by the operating system running on the instance, so you have to either login to the instance to check that, or you can install the [AWS CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html) on the instance to have those values reported to CloudWatch.